# GCC 4.4 does not implement C++11 range loop. What other range loop syntax does it support?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

I have some third party tool that uses some `c++11` features and I'm needing to compile it under an gcc 4.4.  As I'm not at all familiar with `c++11` new features yet I thought I'd ask for help after my google search turned up fruitless.

I've enabled `c++0x` switch but it doesn't help here:

```
for (auto const& fixup : self->m_Fixups)
```

The error produced is:

```
error: expected initializer before ':' token
```

What other range loop syntax which functions equivalently to `C++11` range loop does `GCC 4.4` support?

Comment: So you're asking "I have this non-working code, what would the equivalent, non-working code be in C99?"

Comment: He knows that. He's asking what the equivalent would be in GCC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code is a range-based for-loop which is indeed new in C++11. It is not implemented in GCC 4.4, unlike some other features from C++11. Try this:

```
for( auto it = self->m_Fixups.begin(); it != self->m_Fixups.end(); ++it )
{
    const auto& fixup = *it;
    // the rest of the code...
}
```

The above uses *some* C++11 features which should be available in GCC 4.4.

---

As Ben Voigt pointed out: If you need to make the code more efficient, you might also use this slightly less concise version:

```
for( auto it = self->m_Fixups.begin(), end = self->m_Fixups.end(); it != end; ++it )
{
    const auto& fixup = *it;
    // the rest of the code...
}
```

Comment: +1, although `end()` should be called only once during loop setup and saved.

Comment: I'd suggest using an std::for_each and possibly a lambda instead of writing the loop by hand.

Comment: @AndreKostur Lambdas are also not implemented on GCC 4.4.

Comment: @DanielFrey Ack! I'm off by a version.  Right, no lambdas in 4.4 :(  OK.. std::for_each and a functor.

Answer (score 0):

If you have boost, the following should work with `-std=c++0x` (tested on a gcc 4.4.7, RHEL6 system):

```
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

BOOST_FOREACH(const auto &fixup, self->m_Fixups) {
    ...
}
```